# How to bulkify the code?

Tags: apex

I have written an apex class.Inside for loop I have written some query.Its working fine.

Apex class:

```
public class Rfleet_DZBatchProductUpdate_CLS{
public String strModel1;
public String strModelId;
public String strVersion1;
public List<product2> lstModelprod=new List<product2>();
public List<product2> lstVersionprod=new List<product2>();
public List<product2> lstUpdateParent = new List<product2>();
public void getParenetProductValues() {
    lstModelprod=new List<product2>();
    lstVersionprod=new List<product2>();
    lstUpdateParent = new List<product2>();
    lstModelprod=[SELECT Id,name FROM Product2 where Rfleet_C2G_version_code__c =null and Country_code__c='DZ'];
    for(product2 strModel:lstModelprod) {
        system.debug(strModel.id+':::::'+strModel.name);
        strModel1=strModel.name;
        strModelId=strModel.id;
        system.debug('string Model>>'+strModel1);
        lstVersionprod=[SELECT Id,Rfleet_C2GParentProduct__c,Rfleet_C2G_version_code__c,Parent_Product__c FROM Product2 WHERE Rfleet_C2GParentProduct__c =:strModel1 and Country_code__c='DZ' ];         
        for(product2 strVersion:lstVersionprod) {
            strVersion1=strVersion.id;
            system.debug('success>>');
            system.debug(strVersion1+'::::'+strModel1+'::::'+strModelId);
            Product2 prodt=new Product2();
            prodt.id=strVersion1;
            prodt.Parent_Product__c=strModelId;
            lstUpdateParent.add(prodt);
        }
    }
        update lstUpdateParent;

}
}
```

To bulkify this code I have changed the Logic as below
But the values are not inserted correctly.

Apex:

```
public class Rfleet_DZBatchProductUpdate_CLS{
public String strModel1;
public String strModelId;
public String strVersion1;
public List<product2> lstModelprod=new List<product2>();
public List<product2> lstVersionprod=new List<product2>();
public List<product2> lstUpdateParent = new List<product2>();

public List<String> lstModel = new List<string>();

public void getParenetProductValues() {
    lstModelprod=new List<product2>();
    lstVersionprod=new List<product2>();
    lstUpdateParent = new List<product2>();
    lstModelprod=[SELECT Id,name FROM Product2 where Rfleet_C2G_version_code__c =null and Country_code__c='DZ'];
    for(product2 strModel:lstModelprod) {
        system.debug(strModel.id+':::::'+strModel.name);
        strModel1=strModel.name;
        strModelId=strModel.id;
        system.debug('string Model>>'+strModel1);
        lstModel.add(strModel1);

    }
        lstVersionprod=[SELECT Id,Rfleet_C2GParentProduct__c,Rfleet_C2G_version_code__c,Parent_Product__c FROM Product2 WHERE Rfleet_C2GParentProduct__c in lstModel and Country_code__c='DZ' ];         
        for(product2 strVersion:lstVersionprod) {
            strVersion1=strVersion.id;
            system.debug('success>>');
            system.debug(strVersion1+'::::'+strModel1+'::::'+strModelId);
            Product2 prodt=new Product2();
            prodt.id=strVersion1;
            prodt.Parent_Product__c=strModelId;
            lstUpdateParent.add(prodt);
        }

        update lstUpdateParent;

}
}
```

Please help me out!!

Comment: I see quite some errors in the code indeed. What's the first thing you are running into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use set to hold all the Model names and use that set to query product2

then add those records in map to get in next loop so you don't have query inside for loop.

Only issue was query inside for loop. Not the for inside for since it is just a one level for inside for its ok.

For more detail check below code.

```
public class Rfleet_DZBatchProductUpdate_CLS{
    public String strModel1;
    public String strModelId;
    public String strVersion1;
    public List<product2> lstModelprod=new List<product2>();
    public List<product2> lstVersionprod=new List<product2>();
    public List<product2> lstUpdateParent = new List<product2>();

    public void getParenetProductValues() {
        lstModelprod=new List<product2>();
        lstVersionprod=new List<product2>();
        lstUpdateParent = new List<product2>();

        lstModelprod=[SELECT Id,name FROM Product2 where Rfleet_C2G_version_code__c =null and Country_code__c='DZ'];

        set<String> setModelNames = new set<String>();

        for(product2 strModel:lstModelprod) {
            setModelNames.add(strModel.name);
        }
        map<String, List<Product2>> mapModelNameTolstProduct2 = new map<String, List<Product2>>();
        for(Product2 objProduct2: [SELECT Id, Rfleet_C2GParentProduct__c,
                                          Rfleet_C2G_version_code__c,Parent_Product__c 
                                     FROM Product2 WHERE Rfleet_C2GParentProduct__c IN:setModelNames
                                      and Country_code__c='DZ' ])
        {
            if(mapModelNameTolstProduct2.containsKey(objProduct2.Rfleet_C2GParentProduct__c ))
            {
                mapModelNameTolstProduct2.get(objProduct2.Rfleet_C2GParentProduct__c ).add(objProduct2);
            }
            else
            {
                mapModelNameTolstProduct2.put(objProduct2.Rfleet_C2GParentProduct__c , new List<Product2>{objProduct2});
            }
        }

        for(product2 strModel:lstModelprod) {

            system.debug(strModel.id+':::::'+strModel.name);
            strModel1=strModel.name;
            strModelId=strModel.id;
            system.debug('string Model>>'+strModel1);

            for(product2 strVersion:mapModelNameTolstProduct2.get(strModel.name)) {
                strVersion1=strVersion.id;
                system.debug('success>>');
                system.debug(strVersion1+'::::'+strModel1+'::::'+strModelId);
                Product2 prodt=new Product2();
                prodt.id=strVersion1;
                prodt.Parent_Product__c=strModelId;
                lstUpdateParent.add(prodt);
            }
        }
        upadte lstUpdateParent;
    }
}
```